# How can I get a 0 on the output?

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct, singly-linked-list

So I'm working with the type:

```
typedef struct lligada {
   int valor;
   struct lligada *prox;
} *LInt;
```

And I'm trying to do a function that takes a LInt (ordered) and eliminate the repeated ones, also I need to free the repeated ones.

So my function for that problem is:

```
void remreps (LInt l){
      LInt aux;
      aux =l;

      for (; l!=NULL; ){

          if ((l->prox!=NULL) && (l->valor == (l->prox)->valor)) {
              free (l); 
              l=aux->prox;
              aux=l;
          }

          else {
              l=l->prox;
              aux=l;
          }
    }
}
```

It failed on the second test (using codeboard because university tells me to).

```
Input: [  2  2 ]
Output: expected [  2 ]
        obtained [  0  2 ]
```

Why am I getting this 0 on the output?

Comment: Note: Don't get fancy formatting your code! It is very hard to read already; a larger project will be unreadable! And **never ever** `typedef` an object type pointer!

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @Olaf it was implemented by me teacher... and yeah I have those issues formatting the code!

Comment: `l=aux->prox;` : `aux`  has already been released(`free`'d).

Comment: You *free* the unwanted nodes, but nowhere do you remove them from the list (by updating their predecessors' `prox` pointers).

Comment: Also, do not hide pointer nature behind a typedef, as your code does with type `LInt`.  It is not erroneous to do so, but it usually is more confusing than helpful.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow But i can't change the declaration, I'm not allowed to.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, the given function signature could work if the function removed the *second* of each pair of dupes instead of the first.  In that case, the list head never needs to be removed.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I agree with you. I myself have thought about this.:)

Comment: @JohnBollinger so that can be the problem for that 0, i will try to use other way!

Comment: In that case you should ask your teach how to use this typedef to make it point to a `const` object. Seriously: your teacher should get some practice in C then and work on true projects. My recommendation to you is to get a good C book about modern C (i.e. C99 or standard C11) and not listen too much to your tutor. Feel free to forward this comment to him.

Comment: @Olaf guess I don't want to get "marked" to soon, but I'll check the books for sure, thx!

Comment: @Bruno - How about adding `pointer` tag to this?  Thanks.

Comment: @Nguaial done! New here sry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following function definition.

```
void remreps( LInt l )
{
      while (  l != NULL && l->prox != NULL )
      {
          if ( l->valor == l->prox->valor ) 
          {
              LInt tmp = l->prox;
              l->prox = l->prox->prox;
              free( tmp );
          }
          else 
          {
              l = l->prox;
          }
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct lligada {
   int valor;
   struct lligada *prox;
} *LInt;

void remreps( LInt l )
{
      while (  l != NULL && l->prox != NULL )
      {
          if ( l->valor == l->prox->valor ) 
          {
              LInt tmp = l->prox;
              l->prox = l->prox->prox;
              free( tmp );
          }
          else 
          {
              l = l->prox;
          }
    }
}


LInt push( LInt l, int valor )
{
    LInt tmp = malloc( sizeof( *l ) );

    tmp->valor = valor;
    tmp->prox = l;

    return tmp; 
}

void output( LInt l )
{
    for ( ; l != NULL; l = l->prox )
    {
        printf( "%d ", l->valor );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    LInt l = NULL;

    l = push( l, 2 );
    l = push( l, 2 );

    output( l );
    putchar( '\n' );

    remreps( l );

    output( l );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
2 2 
2
```

Comment: `tmp` is never used.

Comment: @Nguaial Why is it never used? What about free( tmp )?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow - I just figured out what you are doing.  Got it.  My bad.  Thanks!!! (00)

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing code from `Vlad from Moscow`, here is the version that doesn't declare pointer as a type.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct lligada {
   int valor;
   struct lligada *prox;
} LInt;

void remreps( LInt *l )
{
   while (  l != NULL && l->prox != NULL )
   {
      if ( l->valor == l->prox->valor ) 
      {
          LInt *tmp = l->prox;
          l->prox = l->prox->prox;
          free( tmp );
      }
      else 
      {
          l = l->prox;
      }
   }
}


LInt *
push( LInt *l, int valor )
{
   LInt *tmp = malloc( sizeof( *l ) );

   tmp->valor = valor;
   tmp->prox = l;

   return tmp; 
}

void output( LInt *l )
{
    for ( ; l != NULL; l = l->prox )
    {
       printf( "%d ", l->valor );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    LInt *l = NULL;

    l = push( l, 2 );
    l = push( l, 2 );
    l = push( l, 3 );
    l = push( l, 3 );
    l = push( l, 3 );
    l = push( l, 4 );
    l = push( l, 4 );

    output( l );
    putchar( '\n' );

    remreps( l );

    output( l );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 4 4 3 3 3 2 2 
 4 3 2
```

Comment: the only problem is that I'm not allowed to change the declaration, but I appreciate the solution!

Comment: @Bruno - I concur with above comments.  It is much clearer to see if a variable is a pointer or not.  If a type is a pointer itself, it gets confusing.

Comment: I aggre, It is easier to see yeah.